# Dart 3 and widget : "The method 'onChangedStep' isn't defined for the type 'AuthScreen'"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Accross a model view controller system, i'm trying to call a view from the using of widget.
I followed the documentation of DART, but i got the error :
The method 'onChangedStep' isn't defined for the type 'AuthScreen', when i do  widget.onChangedStep(1) line 92 of this) :

```
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Guest.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Password.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int) onChangeStep;
  const AuthScreen({required Key? key, required this.onChangeStep,}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<AuthScreen> createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final RegExp emailRegex = RegExp(r"[a-z0-9\.-]+@[a-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-z]+");
  String _email= '';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          //monte le champ lorsque l'on écrit
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'Bienvenue sur\n'.toUpperCase(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30.0),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'ChopeTonDiplome'.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Esquive la case "Pôle emploi"',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Entre ton email'),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _email = value),
                        validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty || !emailRegex.hasMatch(value) ? "Merci d'entrer une adresse email valide" : null,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Ex: john.walter@domaine.fr',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          elevation: 0,
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 15.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed:  !emailRegex.hasMatch(_email) ? null : () {
                          if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            print(_email);
                            widget.onChangedStep(1);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'continue'.toUpperCase(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seems that it doesn't understand my const Authscreen line 7.
See another file that will help you (i call the onChangedStep(1), so the "TermScreen" in my table here line 22 :

```
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Auth.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Password.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Term.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GuestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const GuestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<GuestScreen> createState() => _GuestScreenState();
}

class _GuestScreenState extends State<GuestScreen> {
  List<Widget> _widgets = [];
  int _indexSelected = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _widgets.addAll([
      AuthScreen(onChangedStep: (index) => setState(() => _indexSelected = index)),
      TermScreen(onChangedStep: (index) => setState(() => _indexSelected = index)),
      PasswordScreen(onChangedStep: (index) => setState(() => _indexSelected = index)),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _widgets.elementAt(_indexSelected),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks for advance!

Tried to call my function using a constant.

Comment: That's a spelling mistake: `widget.onChangedStep(1);` but the field name is `onChangeStep`.